# Pop-up notification (or notification center notification) for battery in OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: notifications, power

I don't have the battery/AC icon turned on because, for the most part, there's no reason for it to be there - I typically get cord-free 5 or so hours at a time, so it seems redundant.

Still, occasionally my laptop will just turn off due to the battery having been depleted.

So, I was wondering if it's possible to have some sort of "Warning, battery is at 1%!" notification in, say, notification center or via Growl?

Currently I just type "pmset -g batt" in the terminal, which I generally have open anyway, to get my estimation. But I would like a more automatic method of doing this, if at all possible.

Comment: What's wrong with the default system alerts which appear on low battery?

Comment: I didn't know there was an alert. Right now the only "alert" I get is that my laptop goes to sleep, no warning before hand.

Comment: @Zrb0529 There's an alert that says "The computer will go to sleep soon to preserve the contents of memory. Please plug in." or some such; for me, it shows up when I get to about 7%.

Comment: Huh. I suppose I somehow turned it off? Any idea where I can turn it back on?

Comment: Is your battery in bad condition? Does it go to suddenly go to sleep with still some percentages left? Check these related questions: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4449/why-does-my-macbook-pro-die-without-warning and http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32540/how-do-i-get-the-low-battery-warning-back-on-my-macbook

Comment: No the battery seems to be fine - it doesn't go to sleep until 0%. It just doesn't give me any warning before hand :-(

Comment: That's odd. It should.

Comment: Huh. Stranger and stranger...